# How to verify if a packet in scapy has a Raw layer?

Tags: scapy, packet, sniffer

Hello all this is my code:

```
#!usr/bin/env python

import scapy.all as scapy
from scapy_http import http

def sniff(interface):
    scapy.sniff(iface=interface, store=False, prn=process_sniffed_packet)

def process_sniffed_packet(packet):
    if packet.haslayer(http.HTTPRequest):`enter code here`
        if packet.haslayer(Raw)
            print(packet[scapy.Raw].load)

sniff("eth0")
```

But, every time I run this code, I get the following error:

```
    if packet.haslayer(Raw)
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: It is definitely possible to check for a Raw layer but here you have an unrelated syntax error.  Could you please format your code using this [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) so that we can see the error.

Comment: Not to be rude, but the issue is so obvious it doesn't seem that you researched anything at all, nor tried anything. Answering this wouldn't actually help you solve (future?) issues, but rather let you depend on forums. This isn't the spirit, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a colon on this line:

```
if packet.haslayer(Raw):
```

And seeing how you used import `scapy.all as scapy` and not from `scapy.all import *`, I think it should also be

```
if packet.haslayer(scapy.Raw):
```